# Huffman compression compressed file is bigger than original file

Tags: java, compression, huffman-code

I have implemented the Huffman Encoding Algorithm in Java using Priority Queues where I traverse the Tree from Root to Leaf and get encoding example as #=000011 based on the number of times the symbol appears in the input. Everything is fine, the tree is being built fine, encoding is just as expected: But the output file I am getting is bigger size than the original file. I am currently appending '0' & '1' to a String on traversing left node and right node of the tree. Here's my write method which writes with an OutputStream:

```
private void writeToFile(Map<Byte, BitSet> dictCode, byte[] data, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        os.write(dictCode.get(data[i]).toByteArray());
    }
 }
```

`data` is my file (the file I will compress) in byte

`Map<Byte, BitSet> dictCode` BitSet is the huffman tree code path to the byte

For exemple Bitset for 10 will be `10={3}` because only the third bit is true: `000100`

I'm writing in bytes so why is my new file lager than the original?

Comment: This can happen if the data isn't compressible, for example if it is already compressed, because you have to add in the dictionary itself.

Comment: But I'm testing with a text file, I don't think it;s normal no?

Comment: Not with text, no. Does your output decompress correctly with a different implementation?

Comment: I have yet to implement the decompression

Comment: That is not what I asked you. I specifically said 'with a different implementation'. In other words, not yours.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. No I did not try with another implementation

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem here is that you are writing out a **byte stream** instead of a **bit stream**.

Assuming in your code the **dictCode** map has a non-trivial entry for each byte in **data** then:

```
private void writeToFile(Map<Byte, BitSet> dictCode, byte[] data, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        os.write(dictCode.get(data[i]).toByteArray());
    }
 }
```

is writing at least one byte to **os** for each byte in in **data**.  So if data is the raw bytes from your input file, you can never write a smaller file with this code.

So for example with the **token stream**

```
111 010 000 1101 111
```

you are writing

```
00000111 00000010 00000000 00001101 00000111
```

instead of

```
11101000 01101111
```

Which is why you are not seeing any compression.

Comment: Thank you, is there any simple fix for this problem?

Comment: I don't think Java supports bit streams out of the box, so you might need to do some tinkering to build up the bytes you want for output.

Comment: Oh I need to bit shift?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines.  There are probably examples around of how to write bits into bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the big help. Appreciate it!